# how to get all accounts records including deleted records from sugarcrm using REST api

Tags: rest, sugarcrm, accounts

following is my code to get result of account module from sugarcrm using rest api
i want to fetch all records including deleted one but it only throws either deleted or non-deleted accounts. but i need both type of record using one request please help

```
$url = "http://localhost/SugarCRM/service/v4/rest.php";
$username = "admin";
$password = "1234";

//function to make cURL request
function call($method, $parameters, $url)
{
    ob_start();
    $curl_request = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($parameters);

    $post = array(
         "method" => $method,
         "input_type" => "JSON",
         "response_type" => "JSON",
         "rest_data" => $jsonEncodedData
    );

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    curl_close($curl_request);

    $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    $response = json_decode($result[1]);
    ob_end_flush();

    return $response;
}

//login --------------------------------------------

$login_parameters = array(
     "user_auth"=>array(
          "user_name"=>$username,
          "password"=>md5($password),
          "version"=>"1"
     ),
     "application_name"=>"RestTest",
     "name_value_list"=>array(),
);

$login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);

/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r($login_result);
echo "</pre>";
*/

//get session id
$session_id = $login_result->id;
$current_date='2014-06-30';//date('Y-m-d');

//get list of records --------------------------------

$get_entry_list_parameters = array(

     //session id
     'session' => $session_id,

     //The name of the module from which to retrieve records
     'module_name' => 'Accounts',

     //The SQL WHERE clause without the word "where".
     'query' => "(accounts.deleted='0' or accounts.deleted='1') AND DATE(accounts.date_entered)='$current_date'",

     //The SQL ORDER BY clause without the phrase "order by".
     'order_by' => "",

     //The record offset from which to start.
     'offset' => '0',

     //Optional. A list of fields to include in the results.
     'select_fields' => array(
          'id',
          'name',
          'billing_address_street',
          'billing_address_city',
          'billing_address_postalcode',
          'billing_address_country',
          'shipping_address_street',
          'shipping_address_city',
          'shipping_address_postalcode',
          'shipping_address_country',
          'website',
          'deleted',
     ),

     /*
     A list of link names and the fields to be returned for each link name.
     Example: 'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(array('name' => 'email_addresses', 'value' => array('id', 'email_address', 'opt_out', 'primary_address')))
     */
     'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
     ),

     //The maximum number of results to return.
     'max_results' => '',

     //To exclude deleted records
     //'deleted' => false,

     //If only records marked as favorites should be returned.
     //'Favorites' => false,
);

$get_entry_list_result = call('get_entry_list', $get_entry_list_parameters, $url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($get_entry_list_result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using the query section, just uncomment and set 'deleted' => true, I am using version 4_1 of the API and that works for me.

It's likely that the default is false and your query is being overridden by it.

Hope that helps

Comment: if i set 'deleted' => true, then it is only showing deleted records but i need both deleted as welll as active